# Why is flutter analyze different from dart analyze?

Tags: flutter, dart, static-code-analysis, linter, dart-analyzer

I am learning Flutter and I've created a simple Android app. I want to follow the best practices, so I've also created a `analysis_options.yaml`:

```yaml
include: package:pedantic/analysis_options.yaml

linter:
  rules:
    public_member_api_docs: true
```

Android Studio correctly updates it's code analysis settings according to the `analysis_options.yaml` and reports violations.

The issue is that when I run `flutter analyze` it doesn't report any of `public_member_api_docs`:

```
flutter analyze
Running "flutter pub get" in flutter-course...         514ms
Analyzing flutter-course...                                 

   info • Unused import: 'package:places/ui/screen/sight_list_screen.dart' • lib/main.dart:2:8 • unused_import
   info • Omit type annotations for local variables • lib/ui/screen/visiting_screen.dart:166:5 • omit_local_variable_types
```

But when I run `dart analyze` it reports ton's of warnings:

```
dart analyze
Analyzing flutter-course... 2.1s

   info • Document all public members at lib/constants.dart:5:16 • (public_member_api_docs)
   info • Document all public members at lib/constants.dart:6:16 • (public_member_api_docs)
   …
   info • Unused import: 'package:places/ui/screen/sight_list_screen.dart' • lib/main.dart:2:8 • unused_import
   info • Omit type annotations for local variables • lib/ui/screen/visiting_screen.dart:166:5 • omit_local_variable_types
```

Why doesn't `flutter analyze` respect the settings from my `analysis_options.yaml`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would assume they use different presets (if you have not configured `analysis_options.yaml`).

The `dart analyze` may default to something that is more appropriate for a published package (`public_member_api_docs`) while `flutter analyze` is more for an app that doesn't have an API that is being consumed.

You can try to add an `analysis_options.yaml` file with some preset configuration like [lint](https://pub.dev/packages/lint) or [pedantic](https://pub.dev/packages/pedantic).

With that you may see more hints and warnings but you have a good baseline and I think both commands should give you the same output.

Alternatively you can start with an empty `analysis_options.yaml` and enable/disable the checks that you want to use one by one.

**Edit**

> Why doesn't flutter analyze respect the settings from my analysis_options.yaml?

I missed this. There have traditionally been differences in the output and also in the formatting of both commands as they have been using different dependency versions. With Dart 2.12 and Flutter 2.0 they are both supposed to be using the same things under the hood.

That being said, there currently seems to be  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/projects/106 in progress to fix the last remaining disparities.